# Equivalent of cmd+down in Numbers

Tags: keyboard, numbers

This is the key combination I would use in MS Excel to jump to the last **contiguous** cell in the current column. Similarly, cmd+shift+down would perform the same jump while selecting all the cells along the way. Is there any way to do the same on Numbers through the keyboard? I am on a MacBook and don't have a numeric keypad on the extreme right of my keyboard.

P.S. Please **DO NOT** suggest links. I need a **solution** that works. So please be sure you have **SUCCESSFULLY tried it YOURSELF** before you post a solution here. The following link, by the way, is full of anomalies and discrepancies and obviously didn't help:

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14849?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

As an illustration of this source' unreliability, check out this example:

> Move to the bottom of the current text area: Command+Down Arrow
>
> Move to the end of the spreadsheet: Command+Down Arrow

Two different functions for the same key combination? Not very reliable, is it?

Comment: Good q. Have you explored: https://www.apple.com/fi/support/numbers/shortcuts/

Comment: Did you? Coz I did (again) and didn't find any reference to this situation there.

Comment: I scrolled through it, but couldn't find an answer for you, which is why I didn't post one. I just referenced it as a helpful link. Regards.

Comment: Well if you already did scroll through it and didn't find my answer, you already know that link isn't helpful in this context, don't you? But thanks anyway. :)

Comment: I browsed through it. Added the link because I thought it may be helpful. As I said, I don't know the answer, but it's a good question. Have a drink...cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is currently not possible.** Numbers provides no method for moving between contiguous cells, whether that be through a menu option or through a keyboard shortcut.

Excel lets you move between contiguous cells as the spreadsheet extends beyond your data so scrolling to the actual end of the sheet would serve no purpose. Conversely, Numbers works with limited tables, so you are expected to limit the end of the table to the end of your data and move through the data in this manner.

You can provide feedback to Apple regarding this at the following page:

- https://www.apple.com/feedback/numbers.html

Comment: Thank you...finally a concrete answer! Though not what I was hoping to hear. This sure is a massive bottleneck for those who are too keyboard dependent. Thanks for your answer again.

Answer (score 1):

While **not editing** the cell press `cmd` ⌘ key along with an arrow key to jump to column or row start, end...
Thus adding the `shift` ⇧ key will select the cells between.

**Note that `shift` ⇧ + click will select everything between as well.** (the only way to achieve what you want with iWork 09')

If you **edit** the cell the `cmd` ⌘ key along with up or down arrow will jump to respectively start and end of the cell.

The `alt` ⌥ along with an arrow key will insert a column or a row.

Use `fn` to scroll the page although in edit mode `ctrl` will do the same.

This works with Numbers 3.2 (iWork 13') I therefore suppose you use iWork 09' and I thank you for at last having found a positive thing about the latest version !

*Remember you may change some (those accessible from the menubar) keyboard shortcuts inside System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts tab for other behavior you should consider getting http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/ *

Comment: If you want to change keyboard shortcuts, you can do it with Keyboard preferences: navigate to shortcuts, then select App Shortcuts and add shortcut you want.

Comment: Well I am using 3.2 (latest) and command+down combination doesn't do what I need it to do. It's not the equivalent of command+down on MS Excel. It jumps to the last cell in the spreadsheet whereas I need it to jump to the last **"contiguous"** cell in the spreadsheet (that's the Excel behavior). This is something I have already mentioned in the question; that's the whole point of looking for an **equivalent** of Excel's cmd+arrow functionality in Numbers.

Comment: I believe there's something I'm not getting... With Excel 2011 and Numbers 3 I press `return` I go to the cell underneath (to go up I also press `shift` ⇧). When I press `tab` I go to the closest cell on the right (the opposite adding `shift` ⇧). If I respectively add `cmd` ⌘ I go to the last row or column (which is not working with the previous versions of Numbers)...

Comment: Ok finally got it just tell "**contiguous cell containing data**" !

Comment: thats what it means.

Comment: Sorry not to have English as my mother tongue, and reading the Oxford Dictionary definition "sharing a common border;[...] next or together in sequence. five hundred contiguous dictionary entries.". Therefore shamefully understanding B2 is next to A2,C2,B1,B3 and not next to ## because in between there's no data.

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely possible as I just found out!

Just use <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> from the top of your data and you should reach the last contiguous cell (while not editing, i.e. you should not have double clicked a cell).

And <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> once you reach the last contiguous cell to go back to the top (again, while not editing).

I had come here to this question and had left after being disappointed and just used Google Sheets or OnlyOffice, but I though there should be a way and sure enough there was this undocumented shortcut.

I say undocumented as neither is the shortcut present in the [online guide](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/numbers/tana45192591/mac) nor in the Keyboard Shortcuts in the Help menu (which I think are the same, but I am not sure).